# Cuda unified memory simple test failed

Tags: c, cuda

I'm a total newbie, here's the first attempt to test out Cuda6 unified memory. After compiling and running, I expected to get:38, 10, but instead I got the result of: 5, 10. Is there anything I did so wrong that makes me totally stupid in this case? Thanks a lot guys!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cuda.h>

__global__ void add2(int *a, int *b)
    {
        *a += 33;
    }

int main(){

    int a = 5;
    int b = 10;

    int *p_a, *p_b;

    cudaMallocManaged(&p_a,sizeof(int));
    cudaMallocManaged(&p_b,sizeof(int));

    p_a = &a;
    p_b = &b;

    add2<<<1,1>>>(p_a, p_b);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    std::cout << *p_a << " " << b << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do cuda error checking. Tell us the GPU and host platform.

Answer (score 2):

`cudaMallocManaged` creates an allocation and sets the pointer accordingly, something like `malloc`. If you then go and wipe out that assigned pointer with

```
p_a=&a;
```

your kernel won't work. Read the section in the CUDA 6 programming guide to learn how UM works.

Instead you could try

```
*p_a=a;
```

and similarly for b.

Comment: Thanks a lot Robert! Now I understand and it's working well! It was such a stupid question :-p